# [DONE]I need to start with Zend Framework 1 but I kinda can't

Tags: zend-framework

So here is my Situation: Some company who hired me is still working with Zend Framework 1 and wants to move on to ZF3 someday.

So I need to learn how to work with Zend Framework 1.12 (for now). My job starts in 2 weeks and I am running out of time. The documentation on the official Zend Framework website showing me a 500 error.

Once I am typing "zf show version" on the linux console it shows me that version 1.12.20 installed, so far so good.

But once I type "zf create project zend", it claims that the project folder is created, but there's no skeleton in there.

When I try this:

```
 composer create-project --stability="dev" zendframework/skeleton-application zend
```

...it creates a skeleton that looks like ZF3. I know there must be an "Application" folder.

What options do I have now?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after I rage-deleted the drive of the virtual machine and re-installed Linux I used the following tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-zend-framework-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps

I can see the skeleton now.